# Higher level libraries for Sybase::DBLib?

Tags: perl, sybase, cpan

Has anyone written something similar to [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Abstract)
for [Sybase::DBLib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sybase::DBLib)? in particular, I'm interested in being able to insert a hash of values into a table without manually forming the sql query myself.

A big issue in working with sybperl is that SQL::Abstract returns bind values and placeholder SQL, not concrete SQL.

The way to create concrete SQL form bind variables has been discussed - http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=839885

I suppose I need to get off my duff and write the code myself if it has not been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely if you switched to using DBD::Sybase instead of Sybase::DBLib then all of the modern DBI-based tools (including DBIx::Class) would be available for you to use.

And anyway, wasn't DBLib deprecated in favour of CTLib about ten years ago?

Comment: switching is not an option at this point. not for me here or other places with large amounts of legacy code riding on sybperl.

I scanned the CPAN docs and didnt see any mention of deprecation.

Comment: The depreciation of Dblib is from Sybase